# nodejs api post method not working , getting cannot /post error

Tags: node.js, api, post

I'm new to node js and when try to perform post operation from html form it says cannot post. can anyone help me.

### Html code

```
<html>
    <body>
<form action="/loginForm" method="POST">
    <input type="text" placeholder="username" name="usrTxt" id="usrTxt">
    <input type="text" placeholder="password" name="pwdTxt" id="pwdTxt">
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</body>
  </html>
```

**app.js**
here i am using routing to passOn page

```
const express = require ('express')

const mongoose = require ('mongoose')
const url = 'mongodb://localhost/XXXDBX'
const app = express ()`enter code here`
app.use(express.json())
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }))

mongoose.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser:true})

const con = mongoose.connection

con.on('open', function(){
    
    console.log('=============================')
    console.log("DB connected.")
    console.log('=============================')
})

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
})

const passOnRoute= require('./routes/passOn')
app.use('/passOn',passOnRoute)

app.listen(3001, function(){
    console.log('=============================')
    console.log("Server runninng..!")
    console.log('=============================')
})
```

**passOn.js**
this js will get the /loginForm url and do further operation

```
router.post('/loginForm', async(req, res) => {
    //console.log("himethod")
    const passOn = new model({
      websitename:req.body.usrTxt,
        password:req.body.pwdTxt
       
    })
   
    try {
       const savelogin= await passOn.save()
       res.json(savelogin)
    }catch(err){
        res.send(err)
    }
})
```

**model.js**
this is mmodel js where it mapping the required model

```
const mongoose = require ('mongoose')
const passSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

websitename : {
    type: String,
    //required : true
},

password : {
    type: String,
  //  required : true
},

})

module.exports = mongoose.model ('passSchema', passSchema)
```

Comment: What exactly is the error showing?

Comment: Cannot POST /loginForm

Comment: Did you try it using postman? Maybe something wrong with the way url is specified.